# Ember data: reuse one model for two guises

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In the app user has two associations - billing address and company address which are identical

```
//address 
export default DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  country: DS.attr('string'),
  zip: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
  //...
});

//user
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  company: DS.belongsTo('address'),
  billing: DS.belongsTo('address')
  //...
});
```

How to pull this kind of trick?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Are you looking for the inverse option?

Comment: afaik, for inversion address model should have two fields: one to be associated as company address and other as billing address.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use a **Polymorphic relationship**. The steps would be (I'm assuming ember-cli, if not the gist is the same):

```
ember generate model address
ember generate model company-address
ember generate model billing-address
```

In `models/address.js` you define the actual address model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  country: DS.attr('string'),
  zip: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
  //...
});
```

Then in the other models you extend from the parent model (polymorphism saves the day!).

company-address

```
import Address from './address';
export default Address.extend({
  // Yeah, its empty.
});
```

billing-address

```
import Address from './address';
export default Address.extend({
  // But, you could add custom fields here and
  // still share the ones with the parent
  // Polymorphism.
});
```

Now in your user model you do this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  company: DS.belongsTo('address', {polymorphic: true}),
  billing: DS.belongsTo('address', {polymorphic: true})
});
```

There is no free lunch though, your JSON has to change its format now:

```
{ name: 'foobar',
  company: {
    // company fields or id if async
    type: 'company-address'
  },
  billing: {
    // billing fields or id if async
    type: 'billing-address'
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you to all this trouble to deal with an issue which intrinsically has nothing to do with polymorphism? The models are the same. Using the same model in two properties does not make it polymorphic and does require polymorphism o handle. Not to mention the fact that Ember Dsta doesn't really do polymorphism well and this approach will require unnecessary and undesirable changes to the API.

Comment: I did extract address as a base model and inherit billing address and company address from it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `inverse` options.
You need two fields on the Address model, one referring to the company with this address, one referring to the user with this address. Then, specify which is which with the `inverse` option.

```
//address 
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  billing: DS.belongsTo('user', { inverse: 'billing' })
  company: DS.belongsTo('user', { inverse: 'company' })
});

//user
export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  company: DS.belongsTo('address'),
  billing: DS.belongsTo('address')
});
```

See http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models#toc_explicit-inverses.

For what you are trying to do, there is no reason whatsoever to define two separate derived models simply in order to get the associations set up properly. `inverse` does exactly what you need.